# Equicardinality of algebraic bases of infinite-dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

V. Bogachev in his textbook "Real and Functional Analysis" wants to show that the algebraic bases of infinite dimensional vector spaces are all of the same cardinality. He proceeds as follows:

If $X$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space and $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are two
algebraic bases, then the cardinality of $\gamma_2$ does not exceed the cardinality
of $\gamma_1$. Indeed, to every element $v \in \gamma_2$, we associate a finite set
of elements $S \subset \gamma_1$ through which it is linearly represented. This
finite set $S$ is associated to at most finitely many elements in $\gamma_2$ (not
exceeding the cardinality of $S$, since by means of $k$ vectors one cannot linearly
express more than $k$ linearly independent vectors). Hence, the cardinality of
$\gamma_2$ does not exceed the cardinality of the set of finite subsets of
$\gamma_1$, which has the same cardinality as $\gamma_1$. Thus, the cardinality of
$\gamma_2$ does not exceed the cardinality of $\gamma_1$, and the opposite inequality
is true as well.

My question: So we assign to every element of $\gamma_2$ a finite subset of $\gamma_1$. We note that two distinct element of $\gamma_2$ could very well go to the same finite subset of $\gamma_1$. How does this show that the cardinality of $\gamma_2$ does not exceed the cardinality of the set of finite subsets of $\gamma_1$? Isn't the given map from $\gamma_2$ to the set of all finite subsets of $\gamma_1$ supposed to be injective for us to each that conclusion? But that map is obviously not injective.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The point is that any finite subset $S$ of $\gamma_1$ can be associated with at most $\#(S)$ elements in $\gamma_2.$ Hence $\#(\gamma_2)$ is less or equal to the cardinality of the family $$\{(S,k)\,:\, S\subset \gamma_1,  1\le k\le \#(S)<\infty\}$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks. I had one more question. Why is the cardinality of the set $$\{ (S, k): S \subset \gamma_1, 1 \leq k \leq #(S) < \infty \}$$ equal to the cardinality of the set of all finite subsets of $\gamma_1$?

Comment: You can split this family into the countable union of families $F_n$ where $n=\#(S).$ Then $$F_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^n \{(S,k)\, :\,S\subset \gamma_1,\, \#(S)=n\}$$ The cardinality of $F_n$ is equal to cardinality of subsets $S$ of $\gamma_1$ such that $\#S=n,$ as the cardinality of every summand is equal to that cardinal number. Thus the cardinality of the union of $F_n$ is less or equal to the cardinality of all finite subsets of $\gamma_1.$